# Using PHP code sniffer in Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony

I want to test out the PHP_CodeSniffer. I installed it in my composer.jason file:

```
"require-dev": {    
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.*",    
}
```

My project is symfony2 and the files I want to check with code sniffer are under src/ directory.

I try to run this command:

```
php php-cs-fixer --level=psr2 --ignore=Tests fix src/
```

but I get this message in my console:

> Could not open input file: phpcs

Answer (score 3):

Codesniffer and php-cs-fixer are two different things!

**Run Codesniffer:**

```
bin/phpcs --standard=phpcs_ruleset.xml src/
```

**Run php-cs-fixer:**

```
bin/php-cs-fixer fix --dry-run --verbose --diff
```

**Composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
    },
    "require-dev": {
        ............ 
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.1",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "2.0.*@dev"
        ............
    },
    ............
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running from wrong directory.

Try to work on `vendor/bin`, here you can find the executable `phpcs` installed by composer

Comment: its wired but it does not appear under my vendor directory

Comment: OK sorry it is in my vendor directory i try to run it like so stil lthe sameproblem : `vendor/bin/php php-cs-fixer --level=psr2 --ignore=Tests fix src/`

Comment: it's `phpcs` not `php-cs`